# Android Studio can not generate Binding class in new activity while use DataBinding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

While using data binding , I have class `MainActivityBinding`.
but when i create new Activity(for example SecondActivity), `SecondActivityBinding` not generated. I removed

`"dataBinding {
       enabled = true
 }"`

from gradle and add it again and make project but `SecondActivityBinding`  not generated. how I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Binding class is generated when you frame your SecondActivity layout.xml file with

```
<layout> ... </layout>
```

> By default, a Binding class will be generated based on the name of the layout 
>   file, converting it to Pascal case and suffixing “Binding” to it. 
>   The above layout file was activity_main.xml so the generate class was ActivityMainBinding.